Opening UNC file with python
How do you open files on a network computer using python through path?
I am currently using
os.startfile

but then I get the error win error2: cannot open file . The file path is correct, and I can open the file by going to win+R.
Appreciate any help you can provide.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
